# Unable to show name with space that is saved in file

Tags: c++

```
ifstream emerg;
emerg.open("emergency.txt");

while ( emerg >> name >> age >> gender >> dis >> roomNo ){
    cout << setw(15) << name << setw(15) << age << setw(15) << gender << setw(25) << dis << setw(15) << roomNo << endl;
}
emerg.close();
```

tried noskipws and skipws

able to cout `string >>name>>` without space, after inserting `string >>name>>` with space anything under name won't be able to cout.

Comment: Always add spaces properly to make it readable. Your code is messy and hard to read

Comment: What is `emergency.txt`?

Comment: i opened that in another fucntion.
ofstream emer;
            emer.open( "emergency.txt" , ios::app );

Comment: `emerg >> name` will do a "tokenized" read, so it will stop reading when encountering a space. if your file uses a certain separator (different from ' '), you can read one line at a time and split the string based on that separator.

Answer (score 0):

When reading a string from a stream using the syntax `stream >> string`, C++ copies the stream content to the string variable until it finds a space char, a new line or the end of the file.

To avoid this, you should perhaps put your data in `emergency.txt` on different lines, and then retrieve the multiple-words strings with `getline(stream, string)`.